# Scraping site using Selenium but issues with content inside the Class

Tags: python, selenium, class, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site to get actor information that looks like this:

```
<fieldset class="table_content">
                        <legend class="hidden nolineHt">Select the actor</legend>
                        <div id="mainDiv">    
                        <div id="wrapperDiv">
                       
                                    <div class="firstRow">
                                               
                                                           
                                                           
                                                                        <input id="actorRow_0_check" name="actorDTO.actors[0].selectedActor" class="sno" type="checkbox" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="_actorDTO.actors[0].selectedActor" value="on">
                                                           
                                               
                                               
                                                <label class="lablemargin1 actor_row_class" id="actorRow_0" for="actorRow_0_check">
                                                            <span class="table_content_colone">
                                                                        <span class="nameBold"JOHN KRAZINSKI, P.H.D.</span><br>
                                                                        <span class="smallFont" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">9255 W NEVERLAND RANCH </span><br>
                                                                        <span class="smallFont" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">Los MAMA
                                                                        ,  </span>
                                                                        <span class="smallFont" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">CA 99999</span>
                                                                        <br>
                                                        <span class="left smallFont tpPad10" aria-hidden="true" aria-disable="true">1-545-555-5555</span>
                                                            </span>          
                                                            <span class="table_content_coltwo textSmall" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">
                                                           
                                                                        <span class="" aria-disabled="disabled" aria-hidden="true">ACTOR </span>         <br>                                       
                                                           
                                                           
                                                                       
                                                                       
                                                                                    <span class="">&nbsp;</span>
                                                                       
                                                           
                                                            </span>
                                                           
                                                                       
                                                                                    <span class="table_content_colthree textSmall" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">Accepting New JOBS</span>           
                                                                       
                                                                       
                                                           
                                                           
                                                                       
                                                                        <span class="table_content_colfour textSmall" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">0.69 miles</span>
                                                           
                                                </label>
                                    </div>
                                                           
                       
                                    <div class="firstRow">
                                               
                                                           
                                                           
                                                                        <input id="actorRow_1_check" name="actorDTO.actors[1].selectedActor" class="sno" type="checkbox" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="_actorDTO.actors[1].selectedActor" value="on">
                                                           
                                               
                                               
                                                <label class="lablemargin1 actor_row_class" id="actorRow_1" for="actorRow_1_check">
                                                            <span class="table_content_colone">
                                                                        <span class="nameBold">PAMELA BEASLEY, L.C.S.W.</span><br>
                                                                        <span class="smallFont" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">2222 PENNSYLVANIA AVE </span><br>
                                                                        <span class="smallFont" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">West PITTSBURGH
                                                                        ,  </span>
                                                                        <span class="smallFont" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">CA 99999</span>
                                                                        <br>
                                                        <span class="left smallFont tpPad10" aria-hidden="true" aria-disable="true">1-555-555-5555</span>
                                                            </span>          
                                                            <span class="table_content_coltwo textSmall" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">
                                                           
                                                                        <span class="" aria-disabled="disabled" aria-hidden="true">ACTOR </span>         <br>                                       
                                                           
                                                                        <span class="" aria-disabled="disabled" aria-hidden="true">ACTOR </span>         <br>                                       
                                                           
                                                           
                                                                       
                                                                       
                                                                                    <span class="">&nbsp;</span>
                                                                       
                                                           
                                                            </span>
                                                           
                                                                       
                                                                                    <span class="table_content_colthree textSmall" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">Accepting New JOBS</span>           
                                                                       
                                                                       
                                                           
                                                           
                                                                       
                                                                        <span class="table_content_colfour textSmall" aria-disable="true" aria-hidden="true">0.79 miles</span>
                                                           
                                                </label>
                                    </div>
```

The issue is that i would like to get the name, address, city, phone, job, and whether they're currently employed or not.

I have tried to choose each one of those elements individually but the issue is that when i do that, the XPATH displays this:

```
//*[@id="actorRow_0"]/span[1]/span[1]
```

but then when I check the XPATH for the second actor it displays this:

```
//*[@id="actorRow_1"]/span[1]/span[1]
```

The XPATH is completely different. So when I run the scraper I only get the information for the first actor.

I have tried to bypass grabbing each element individually and settled for just grabbing everything that is blocked together. This is the code I currently have:

```
main = driver.find_element_by_id('mainDiv')
sections = main.find_elements_by_class_name('firstRow')


actor_info = []

#print(section.text)
for actor in sections:
    first_blox = pcp.find_element_by_class_name('table_content_colone').text
    second_blox = pcp.find_element_by_class_name('table_content_coltwo').text

    actor_items = {
        'first_block' : [first_blox],
        'second_block' : [second_blox]
    }

    actor_info.append(actor_items)
```

The issue I am encountering now is that since im focusing on pulling a list of values, only the last value gets returned to me at the end.

Any help on either outcome would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT - Hey guys, just wanted to let everyone know that my answer to the second question was that i was inputing .text at the end of actor.find_element_by_class_name('table_content_colone').text the solution was to replace text with innerText and i was able to acquire the whole block i was scrapping.

Comment: Hey guys, just wanted to let everyone know that my answer to the second question was that i was inputing  .text at the end of                                                                                                   
actor.find_element_by_class_name('table_content_colone').text

the solution was to replace text with innerText and i was able to acquire the whole block i was scrapping.

Comment: What info are you expecting within `actor_info = []`?

Comment: if you resolved some problem than you could put it as answer or write information in question - because people may not read comments and they may try to resolve problem which you already resolved.

Comment: you could change indentations in HTML to make shorter lines - and it would be more readable.

Comment: if items/actors have different ID then you should find different value to recognize all actors - without ID. OR you could use `contains(@id, "actorRow_")` to find all actors

Comment: maybe better show URL for this page. We will see if there are better objects to create xpath which gets all actors. And put it in question, not in comments. More people will see it - so more people may help you.

Comment: maybe you get only last value because you append values in wrong place - ie. outside `for`-loop but you should do it inside loop. But you didn't show [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can't run it and see problem. So we can't help you.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I am expecting the name, address, city, phone in variable first_block and job, and whether they're currently employed or not in the second_block variable.

Comment: @furas ok, sorry about that. will do next time.

Comment: so you get answer also next time :)